# move_uploaded_file in PHP not working after transfering my site to new hosting server?

Tags: php, file-upload, php-5.3

So I transferred my website from Godaddy to a rackspace cloud hosting plan ... Now I'm facing an issue with pictures not being able to be uploaded from my website , I checked my script to debug and trace the problem , and the problem arises at the move_uploaded_file built in function , it returns FALSE ... I gave the 777 permission to the upload file , but it still isn't working ... Any idea why .. Below is the uploading function

```
function upload_file($mid,$image,$folder){  
    $image_name = false;
    if($_FILES[$image]['name']!=""){  
        $tmpImageName = $_FILES[$image]['name'];
        $uploadedfile=$_FILES[$image]['tmp_name'];
        $extension=getExtension($_FILES[$image]['name']);       
        if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="JPG" || $extension=="jpeg" || $extension=="JPEG" || $extension=="gif" || $extension=="GIF" || $extension=="png" || $extension=="PNG"){
            // FIX limit max image file size to 3.5MB - 2012-06-14 10:48

            if($_FILES[$image]['size'] > 3200000) {
                Set_Display_Message("Invalid image size for file {$tmpImageName}! Please upload file smaller than 3.5MB.");
            } else {
                // FIX limit max image dimensions to 3500x3500px - 2012-06-14 10:48
                list($width, $height, $attr) = getimagesize($uploadedfile);
                if(3500 < $width || 3500 < $height) {
                    Set_Display_Message("Invalid image dimensions for file {$tmpImageName}! Please upload file smaller 3500x3500 px.");
                } else {
                    $image_name=getfileName($_FILES[$image]['name']).$mid.mt_rand(1000,9999).".".$extension; //var_dump($image_name);
                    $NotVail_files = file_validation('image',$uploadedfile);  //var_dump($uploadedfile); var_dump($folder);
                    if($tmpImageName!="" && $uploadedfile!="" && $image_name!="" && $NotVail_files){    
                        @move_uploaded_file($uploadedfile, $folder."/".$image_name); //var_dump(move_uploaded_file($uploadedfile, $folder."/".$image_name)); var_dump($_FILES); exit;
                    }
                }   
            }
        } else {             
            Set_Display_Message("Invalid file format! Please upload only image type: .jpg,.jpeg,.gif,.png......");   
        }

    }
return $image_name;
}
```

Comment: Did you set the directory rights correctly?

Comment: Are the temporary directory and the destination on different mount points?

Comment: what are mount points ... I never heard of this ...

Comment: @CharlotteDunois  yes ..

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="file" id="FileUpload1" style="position:absolute;" name="upload">

<input type="submit" id="Button1" name="image submit" value="Submit" style="position:absolute;width:96px;height:25px;">
```

That should work for you as I'm using this script on my site.
Just having a problem now after a year the server seems to have upgraded where it's needing tweaks to redirect page once the file uploads.